# How do I check if some of the lists have exactly two values and are among certain ranges?

Tags: python, list

I have a file:

```
A1=[0.65,0.64,1.01]
A2=[1.13,1.21]
A3=[0.75,1.11]
A4=[]
A5=[0.65]
A6=[0.95,1.83]
```

If at least two of the six lists have exactly two values(from 0 to 3 values), and  0.45<=values<1.4, then print "A=True"
In this case, A2,A3 has two values, and values of  A2,A3 are among [0.6,1.4], so it's true.

I tried sth like this:

```
alist=[A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6]
blist=[]
y=[]
for row in alist:
def two_value(alist):
   for i in alist:
      if len(i)==2:
        blist.append(i)
   return False
#I will get three list True 
#if len(blist) >=2:
#check the blist if they are among the range of [0.6,1.4]   
def range(blist):
    for ls in blist:
            for i in ls:
                x =all(1.4>=i>=0.6 for i in ls.split(','))
                y.append(x)
```

I'm not familiar with python  Are there any ways to achieve this in python or bash ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file looks like this:

```
A1=[0.65,0.64,1.01]
A2=[1.13,1.21]
A3=[0.75,1.11]
A4=[]
A5=[0.65]
A6=[0.95,1.83]
```

Suppose that data's in `foo.txt`. First, let's get a file handle:

```
results = {}

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
   ...
```

We now want to iterate over the lines of the file, processing each line in turn. For each line we process, we'll check:

1. Does it have exactly two elements?
2. Are both elements in the range [i, j]?

Since both must be true for a list to pass, we should stop processing a line whenever we know *either* condition is not met.

First, let's split each line on the delimiter (`=`):

```
results = {}

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            key, value = line.split("=")  # This is called "unpacking".
        except ValueError:
            # If we don't have enough values to unpack, then = isn't
            # in the line: skip it.
            continue
```

Next, let's use `json.loads` to take each JSON-encoded string array into a list of  numbers. Once we have a list, we can check its length: if it's greater than two, it can't be a candidate, so we move on.

```
import json

results = {}

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            key, value = line.split("=")  # This is called "unpacking".
        except ValueError:
            continue

        l = json.loads(value.strip())
        
        if len(l) != 2:
            continue
```

Next, let's check whether all the elements in the list are in the desired range. If they are, we track the list. Otherwise, we do nothing.

```
import json

results = {}

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            key, value = line.split("=")  # This is called "unpacking".
        except ValueError:
            continue

        l = json.loads(value.strip())
        
        if len(l) != 2:
            continue

        # This type of check is O(n), but we KNOW l has exactly
        # two elements, so it should be OK.
        if all(val >= 0.6 and val <= 1.4 for val in l):
            results[key] = l

# If we have at least one result, print it.
if results:
    print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you. very clear. It's very useful for me apply it in clinical diagnosis.

Comment: One more question, if I have more than 10 similar files like: foo.txt, foo1.txt, foo2.txt ...foo10.txt. How could I do it in a for loop?

Comment: Extending this for multiple files is straightforward: it’s just an outer loop varying the file name.